# How can I allow my mouse cursor to pass from larger monitor to smaller based on relative positioning?

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse-cursor

I currently have a monitor setup like below:

```
                          +----------------------+
                          |                      |
                          |                      |
+-----------++-----------+|                      |
|           ||           ||      3840x2160       |
| 1920x1200 || 1920x1200 ||                      |
|           ||           ||                      |
+-----------++-----------++----------------------+
```

I want to find a way to allow my mouse to always go from the 3840x2160 monitor to the 1920x1200 without it getting blocked because the larger monitor can't align fully.

I have been searching for a registry hack or a software product that could allow the cursor to pass from the larger to the smaller based on relative location, instead of exact pixel location. The goal being that the mouse cursor is never blocked at the edge of the 3840x2160 when attempting to go to the left 1920x1200 monitor.

Any help in solving this is appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible in windows without additional software. Do note, Asking for a software recommendation is considered Off-Topic.

Comment: use an AutoIt script to watch the position of the cursor and to move it downwards when it gets near the "wall" ......... https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: @LPChip I am asking for help solving a problem and if a 3rd party software package can enable this feature to solve it this it should nto be off-topic as the goal is to allow this ability.

Comment: @jsotola AutoIt or similar scripting/macro wouldn't be a proper solution. I appreciate the suggestion though. If Microsoft had a way to enable this, or a 3rd party software product could be installed to resolve it then that would solve the issue.

Comment: The marked solution on the one marked as a dup is wrong, and my questions I think is better worded. The solution is Display Fusion solves this problem. SO it is possible with additional software which was a possible option I presented as acceptable. Therefore makes my question different enough that Display Fusion as an answer would be marked as correct here. I have already installed it and verified it solves the issue.

Comment: @RodneyFoley, AutoIt is a 3rd party software product

Comment: @jsotola AutoIt is not a 3rd party software product it is a Scripting Language. Installing it doesn't do anything until you run a script written in its language. If I install it it will not do anything to address this issue without writing the script myself or finding one. DisplayFusion and UltraMon are 3rd party products that once you install them you check ONE box and it solves this issue.

Comment: i understand what you are saying ... AutoIt has the capability to generate a stand alone executable though .... it allows you to tailor the behaviour precisely to your requirements .... the 3rd party product that you mention may even have been written this way (not saying that it was)

Comment: I'm fully aware of what AutoIt can & cannot due & its standalone executable really isn't more than a bootstrap for the scripting engine with the scripts embedded in it and running them. 

No they were not written this way UltraMon & DisplayFusion dont use AutoIt or its offshoot AutoHotKey. I've a lot of experience with AutoIt in my professional life & I have chosen never to use it at home for a number of reasons.

I am not sure what AutoIt bug you have and why you are pushing it so much I know you are not the creator as you are way nicer than he is. Please drop this I've solved the issue.